# Убрать пустое расстояние CSS

Tags: html, css

Тут код - [GitHub](https://github.com/xqzmy-afk/govnocode/commit/293073e8803ed881e34067de7063a4d1645770b6)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извиняюсь сразу что вы увидели этот код.
Не понимаю почему текст появляется внизу а не сразу после серого фона

Comment: В идале к скринам ещё бы прилагать код, и в вопросе что-то не получилось со скрином.

Comment: я сделал открытым https://github.com/xqzmy-afk/govnocode/commit/293073e8803ed881e34067de7063a4d1645770b6

Comment: решил эту проблему,форма с relative оставляла слишком много пустого пространства,благодаря https://fooobar.com/questions/104072/positionrelative-leaves-an-empty-space этому трюку удалось избавиться от пустого пространства

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз начал свойствам position:relative; расставлять на места, то чтоб текст оказался в нужном месте можешь сделать примерно так

```
.forp {
            position:relative;
            left: 15px;
            top: -200px;
            font-size:20px;
        }
```

И все встанет на свои места.Почему произошел разрыв?

Ты создал fon1, menu,потом fon2, и задал им определенную высоту.

Следующие элементы fotka1,text,fotka2,input1,form228 ты начал размещать после fon2 и расстанавливать их на места используя position:relative, исходя из их место расположения под fon2

Но от того что на экране ты им изменил позицию и они находятся будто в блоке fon2,каждый из них все равно находиться в общем потоке под блоком fon2.Таким образом под блоком fon2 у тебя fotka1,text,fotka2,input1,form228, от каждого этого блока берется высота и получается тот самый большой пробел. Ты ж написал forp не сразу после fon2. Но почему то ожидаешь что он должен появиться под ним. Нет, он правильно появляется под fotka1,text,fotka2,input1,form228 которые занимают место.

А от того что ты их relative-ом сместил, это не говорит что они исчезли из потока.

Чтоб более детально понять что я до этого написал, убери text,fotka2,input1,form228 из html оставив под fon2 только fotka1, и ты увидишь уже сразу что тот пробел меняется высотой.Добавь к fotka1 в css свойства height:"50px" и поиграй значениями,и ты увидишь как меняется твое расстояние.

Далее мой совет ,так не верстай!Делай блоки которые находятся логически как бы в другом блоке внутри, примерно такая у тебя должна быть структура.

```
<div class="fon1">
    <div class="fotka">
        <img src="kekw/lox.png" width="100">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="lox">

            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="fon2">
    <div class="fotka1"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="fotka2"></div>
    <div class="text2"></div>
    <div class="input1"></div>
   <<div class="form228"></div>
</div>

<div class="forp">
    <p>Текст тут а не где кончается серый фон(почему?)</p>
</div>
```

И тогда задавая позиции внутренних блоков относительно родительского, ты будешь понимать что где располагается. И тогда такой беды у тебя не будет.И другим будет понятно что в чем находиться.

Comment: Спасибо,буду по этой структуре верстать